# SAS - Change the format of a column in a proc imported CSV

Tags: csv, sas

I cannot quite figure out how to change the format of a column in my data file. I have the data set proc imported, and it guessed the format of a specific column as numeric, I would like to to be character-based.

This is where I'm currently at, and it does not change the format of my NUMBER column:

```
proc import
    datafile = 'datapath'
    out = dataname
    dbms = CSV
    replace
;
    format NUMBER $8.
;
    guessingrows = 20000
;
run;
```

Comment: Note there is no need to use PROC IMPORT for a text file. Just write your own data step to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could import the data and then format after using - I believe the following would work.

```
proc sql;
   create table want as
  select *, 
      put(Number, 4.) as CharacterVersion
 from data;
```

quit;

Comment: would this work the same in a join? I seem to still be having trouble with this:

x left join y on put(x.number, 4.) = y.number

Comment: Did this part first, then joined later in a separate table. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the help file (search for "Processing Delimited Files in SAS")

> If you need to revise your code after the procedure runs, issue the RECALL command (or press F4) to the generated DATA step. At this point, you can add or remove options from the INFILE statement and customize the INFORMAT, FORMAT, and INPUT statements to your data.

Granted, the grammar in this section is horrific!  The idea is that the `IMPORT` Procedure generates source code that can be recalled and modified for subsequent submission.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the type/format via PROC IMPORT. However, you can write a data step to read in the file and then customize everything. If you're not sure how to start with that, check the log after you run a PROC IMPORT and it will have the 'skeleton' code. You can copy that code, edit it, and run to get what you need. Writing from scratch also works using an INFILE and INPUT statement.